# modify html/css code with pure css, without any html modifications to align divs

Tags: css, html, css-float, height

There are many `<div style="float:left;"></div>` in a one big div.

http://jsfiddle.net/h3EY9/1/

So, the widths are the same but the heights could be different (depending on the text inside).
Is it possible to align that `div`s so that it looks good - it goes by 3 in a row. 
That means, it looks like [this http://jsfiddle.net/h3EY9/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/h3EY9/2/) or this:

```
123
456
789
...
```

**using css only?**

The html solution: I could wrap every 3 divs into `<div style="overflow:hidden;"></div>` like [here http://jsfiddle.net/h3EY9/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/h3EY9/2/), however I'm not allowed modify the html code, the html solution is not preferable. I'm curious if a pure css solution is possible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `clear:left` for every third `<div>`:

```
.inner-div:nth-child(3n+1){ clear:left; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h3EY9/4/

More about [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) on MDN.

Comment: You'd probably need some additional solution if you have to support IE8 and below.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it is not for IE8-. Thank  you for pointing that!

Comment: Of cause, your solution works, but i think, the way doing it with inline-block is it bit better. All depend on what he is going for...

Answer (score 3):

Use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align` for your divs. And remove the wrapper-divs. See this [Demo-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3EY9/7/).

```
.inner-div{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin: 2px;
    position: relative;
    width: 140px;
    min-height:50px;
}
```